# Zend Form Input Type File Validator RegEx

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

is there a way to give a form fileupload inputfield a regexp for the filename?

I tried it like that:

```
$image1 = $form1->addElement('file', 'image1', array(
                               'validators' => array(
                                    array('Count', false, '1' ),
                                    array('Size', false, '10MB'),
                                    array('Extension', false, 'jpg'),
                                    array('regex', false, '/^[a-z]\.jpg$/'),
                                ),
                                'required'   => false,
                                'label' => 'Image1(jpg/tif)'
            ));
```

But its not working...

Can anyone give me a hint?

TIA, Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with a Callback validator and have the regexp checked in the callback method:

---

```
$form1->getElement('file')->addValidator(new Zend_Validator_Callback('checkFilename'));

...

public function checkFilename($file = null, $formData = null) {
    $filename = $file->getValue();
    if (preg_match(/^[a-z]\.jpg$/, $filename)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```